# How to check one of multiple checkbox group listed in on PDCheckbox field?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Using PDFBox 2.0.8 for the first time on PDF files I don't have any control over.  Cycling through the form fields I get this output for one of the fields.

```
field = Check Box5{type: PDCheckBox value: COSName{}}
field.getFullyQualifiedName() = Check Box5
field.getFieldType() = Btn
```

The actual field on the PDF is an option of choosing one of 4 options ('CheckBox Group' if you will?).  Call them A, B, C, D.  So the end user experience is that if i choose C it unchecks A.

When I do the following:

```
if(field.getFullyQualifiedName().equals("Check Box5")){
  PDCheckBox checkBox = (PDCheckBox) field;
  checkBox.check();
}
```

It checks 'A' as expected (sort of), but subsequent `check()`s do not make any difference.  How does one choose 'C'?

EDITS:

1. [Actual PDF Downloaded Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/big7e2l1p7z1dtb/EstateInfo-000821.pdf?dl=0).

Comment: Then it isn't a checkbox, but a radio button series. Call setValue. Or it is done with javascript. The best would be to share your PDF.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I posted a link to download the PDF.  I would argues its not a checkbox too, but the PDFBox is saying it is.

Comment: Very mysterious: the fields do not have the radio flag set (they have `/Ff 0`), but they behave like it. And there's no javascript.